# Declare a column of type 'not-null-string' array in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Using PostgreSQL 9.6 I can create a column with type 'not-null-array of string' with:

```
CREATE TABLE example (
    foo TEXT[] NOT NULL
);
```

but this allows the elements to be null, i.e I can do:

```
INSERT INTO example VALUES('{NULL}')
```

Is there a way to instead create a column with type 'not-null-array of not-null-string'? I'd like something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE example (
    foo (NOT NULL TEXT)[] NOT NULL
);
```

but it's not syntactically valid. Is there a valid way to express this?

Comment: I asked similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63932721/why-in-postgresql-enum-type-array-null-values-allowed) related to enum type array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simpler since pg 9.5, with the addition of `array_position()`

```
CREATE TABLE example (
    foo TEXT[] NOT NULL check (array_position(foo, null) is null)
);
```

You might also want to check for an empty array:

```
CREATE TABLE example (
    foo TEXT[] NOT NULL check (foo <> '{}' and array_position(foo, null) is null)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the function:

```
create or replace function are_elements_not_null(arr anyarray)
returns boolean language sql immutable 
as $$
    select bool_and(elem is not null)
    from unnest(arr) as elem 
$$;
```

in a check constraint:

```
create table example(
    foo text[] check(are_elements_not_null(foo))
);

insert into example values
(array[null]);

ERROR:  new row for relation "example" violates check constraint "example_foo_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains ({NULL}).
```

Note that the column still may be null or may contain an empty array. If you want to exclude these cases expand the definition in the way:

```
create table example(
    foo text[] check(are_elements_not_null(foo) and foo <> '{}') not null
);
```