# Why in PostgreSQL enum type array null values allowed?

Tags: postgresql

I am working with a PostgreSQL DB, and use an array of an enum type as one of the columns.

```
CREATE TYPE my_type_enum AS ENUM ('value1', 'value2', 'value3');
ALTER TABLE "my_table" ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS "my_column" my_type_enum ARRAY;
```

The `enum` gives me to add only valid values that it contains, but I also can add a `null` elements to it.

So, to prevent saving `null` elements to DB, I added a filter in the app, but I wonder if there is a definition in PostgreSQL not to allow adding `null` elements to `array`?

P.S. I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45576834/declare-a-column-of-type-not-null-string-array-in-postgresql) suggestion to add function as part of the column definition, but this is not what I asked.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a check constraint to prevent elements with NULL values.

```
alter table my_table
  add constraint no_null_element 
  check (cardinality(my_column) = cardinality(array_remove(my_column, null)));
```

---

A cleaner solution would be a normalized one-to-many relationship with a foreign key column defined as `not null`

Answer (score -2):

another way

IF array_length(arrayname, 1) > 0 THEN
transactions
END IF;